# Backend platform for lean sideproject with advanced tagscheme

Tags: backend, parse-platform, stackmob

I'm an experienced frontend developer (Backbone, Coffeescript) and designer with little to no skills concerning backend stuff. I want to build a sideproject without having to worry about setting up a server or maintaining a database. The project has to be as lean and less timeconsuming as possible but being able to implement some kind of user authentication and an advanced tagscheme will be important.

I'm considering using a backend as a service platform like http://parse.com or http://stackmob.com but still wonder if there are better ways to implement the project I have in mind. Given my description of the situation: Which platform / framework / stack would you recommend?

Answer (score 10):

Full Disclosure - I'm the Platform Evangelist at StackMob ;-)

The project you are describing is a very good fit for what StackMob offers.  Our goal is to increase developer productivity.  No server setup required and you can create your API from your front-end in a few lines of JavaScript code.  Our open source JavaScript SDK is built on top of backbone.js.

Some example code for declaring your model and creating your schema would look like this.

```
var ToDo = StackMob.Model.extend({schemaName:'todo'});

var todo = new ToDo({action : 'take out the trash'});
todo.create({
  success: function(model){
     // do something
  },
  error: function(error) {
    //alert user of error
  }
});
```

The create method invokes a RESTful call to StackMob and passes the object.  We infer what type of data is passed and create your schema.

StackMob offers the most flexibility among the other players in this space.  We support custom-code, so you can write custom business logic in Java, Scala or Clojure, package it as a JAR file and upload it to StackMob servers.  Then call the custom method, execute the code and return a JSON response.

We also integrate with Github, so you can auto deploy your HTML5 apps to StackMob servers and remove any need for hosting your app elsewhere.

Let me know if you have more questions about StackMob.

Comment: Thx for your answers! Still haven't made the decision between StackMob and Parse yet but I'll definitely take one of those two platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The team over at Parse.com is very responsive, the docs are OK to get you started (I'm sure it'll grow) and I'm sure you can do what you want in terms of tagging - see my other questions for using the Parse.Relation class.

I haven't tried StackMob but heard good things about it as well.

Meteor.com will be the next thing I try if Parse fails me :P Learning curve is close to zero with these Mongo-based (flexible schema) BaaS's :) especially since you're already familiar with Backbone.

I'm playing with Parse since 3 weeks, feel free to ask more detailed questions!

Comment: Thx for your answers! Still haven't made the decision between StackMob and Parse yet but I'll definitely take one of those two platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend taking a look at Cloud CMS (http://www.cloudcms.com).

Full Disclosure - I'm one of the founders of Cloud CMS.  So I'm a big fan.  Plus, I think it's awesome.

Our platform is entirely built around JSON and JSON Schema for modeling content.  You just write content in and it's immediately versioned, indexed and available for query and full-text search.  Our data store is fully consistent with content modeling (types, properties, associations, aspects) and validation.  Basically, we try to handle all the hard stuff so that you can just get coding.

We provide drivers for native devices as well as JavaScript/HTML5, Java and other languages.  Our JavaScript driver features asynchronous chaining so that you code becomes really simple. Like this:

```
// define an article using JSON schema
branch.create({
    "qname": "custom:article",
    "properties": {
        "header": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "rating": {
            "type": "number",
            "minValue": 0
        },
        "author": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
});

// create an article
branch.createNode({
    "_type": "custom:article",
    "header": "Pink Floyd Reunites for World Tour!",
    "rating": 50,
    "author": "gilmour"
});

// search for articles using full-text search
branch.searchNodes("Pink Floyd").each(function() {
    $('body').append("Found an article: " + this.get('header') + "<br/>");
});

// query for articles with structured MongoDB query
branch.queryNodes({
    "author": "gilmour", 
    "rating": { 
        "&gt": 40 
    } 
}).count(function(count) {
    $('body').append("There were: " + count + " total articles");
});
```

That's a rough example.  There's a lot more available on the web site.

Cloud CMS is worth a look because it's a genuine content platform built on top of JSON, MongoDB and a pure cloud architecture.  It scales well but also has a lot of the enterprise-class features of big old expensive software.  We really want to keep costs low and so we've elected to go with a pure metered billing model (as a utility, kind of like your electric bill).